# How can I fix this "Generator expression must be parenthesized if not sole argument" error?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am writing a program to censor some words.

```
def censor(sentence, word):
  splitted_sentence = sentence.split()  #splitted_sent = ["he", "is", "a", "clucking", "boy"]
  censored = [item.replace(item, "*" * len(item) for item in word)]
  return censored
print censor("he is a clucking boy", "clucking")
```

In this example, what I want to do is to filter the word "clucking" in a sentence. But when I run it, it says:

> Generator expression must be parenthesized if not sole argument.

Comment: Could you have not chosen a more 'child friendly' word for your example? SO is for all people of all ages and backgrounds you know

Comment: just `return sentence.replace(item, "*" * len(item)).split()`

Comment: @Chris_Rands first of all, thanks for your answer, I would definitely choose a more appropriate word next time. Next, when I try to run the code after having modified the code as suggested by you, it printed : "['he', 'is', 'a', 'clucking', 'boy'] instead of ['he', 'is', 'a', 'xxxxxxxx', 'boy']

Answer (score 0):

No need of list-comprehension to complicate the simple things.Please find below simple code for doing same thing.

```
def fun(sen,word):
    sen=sen.replace(word, len(word)*"*")
    return sen

print(fun("he is a clucking boy","clucking")) #he is a ******** boy
```

Answer (score -3):

Probably you misplaced a parenthesis. Try this:

```
censored = [item.replace(item, "*" * len(item)) for item in word]
```

Comment: it's a paranthesis `)`, this is a brace `}`, anyway flag and don't answer typo errors